# how can i check the source code of a library installed in databricks?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, libraries, azure-databricks

I need to review the "source code" of a library that was developed privately in the company for a product and uploaded to databricks.

Thanks!

Comment: ask them for source code...

Comment: The person who developed the bookstore unfortunately passed away and nothing of his work could be recovered for personal reasons.